# How to avoid crashing when the imported file is not available ?..IOS 7

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, xcode5

i have a small library which uses the SVProgressHUD and i want if the user removes the SVProgressHUD from my library the library won't crash..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into __has_include macros:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#include-file-checking-macros